# lp commands not displaying meaningful messages

Tags: linux, printing, redhat-enterprise-linux, cups

We have CUPS 1.6.3. in 2 RHEL7 environments, A & B.

On A, when we issue lpstat command we get list of active jobs. Man page says
*When run with no arguments, lpstat will list active jobs queued by the current user.*

But on B, instead of giving meaningful information, it simply returns a bunch of these messages:

```
lpstat: Success
lpstat: Success
lpstat: Success
```

Similarly, lp command issued on A returns expected message:

```
request id is print_test-3 (1 files(s))
```

Not so on B.

```
lp: success
```

Missing something, but what?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Our CUPs installation was fine.

The problem turned out to be that the print server was blocking traffic on port 631.

Firewall rules showed the port to be open, but there was an SELinux policy blocking on port 631.

Why the lp commmands have the word success is a mystery, but with the port fully open, we get the expected results now.